# How to use usage stats manager to a list of running apps in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, usagestatsmanager

I can't seem to find any good resources that show how to use UsageStatsManager in c# to get a list of all apps that are running. I've seen that activity manager and get running tasks is no longer working in versions after Lollipop and am trying to create a task manager app of sorts that requires this info.

I have used:

```
        UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)context.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService("usagestats");
        long time = TimeUtils.CurrentTimeMillis();
        long beginTime = time - 1000 * 10;


        List<UsageStats> stats = usageStatsManager.QueryUsageStats(UsageStatsInterval.Daily, beginTime, time).ToList<UsageStats>();

        foreach (var item in stats)
        {
            serviceInfo.Add(item.PackageName);
        }
```

With TimeUtils as:

```
    public class TimeUtils
    {
        private static readonly DateTime Jan1st1970 = new DateTime
        (1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        public static long CurrentTimeMillis()
        {
            return (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - Jan1st1970).TotalMilliseconds;
        }
    }
```

This returns null, I'm not sure if this could be a permissions error? I am using the user permission for Package_Usage_stats:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: "...user of the device still needs to grant permission through the Settings application..."

Answer (score 1):

When using the `UsageStatsManager` api, the user of the device still needs to grant permission through the **Settings** application even the permission has been decalred.

Check the doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager

You can guide the user to open the Apps with **Usage Access** setting page with the following code.

```
btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionUsageAccessSettings));
};
```